# Table leaves margin after jQuery.toggle() in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, toggle

This problem is observed in Firefox only.

```
<script>
function toggle_combo()
{
    $('.combo').toggle();
}
</script>

<table>
<tr onclick='toggle();>
<td> - </td>
</tr>
<tr class="combo" style="display:none">
<td> - </td>
</tr>
<tr class="combo" style="display:none">
<td> - </td>
</tr>
</table>
////here is that <br> i forgot to mention
<br>
<table>
<tr>
<td> - </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So I click once to show the hidden table rows of table1 and table2 is moved down the page to make space (which is fine).

But then when I hide the rows of table1, table2 doesn't go back to its initial place but rather stays static, leaving a margin between the two tables.

I've tried setting float:left to the tables but it didn't work. What next?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS3 code, try adding:

```
margin: 0 !important;
padding: 0 !important;
```

Add that to the table. Also, check if there actually is margin or padding by going into Inspect Element.

Best Luck,
Ben A.K.A BlackSky

Comment: It actually worked, but I found what the actual problem was. There was a <br> I forgot to mention between the tables and when I removed it there was no need for resetting the margins. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this `<br>` between the tables was throwing off Firefox somehow into setting new margins for the tables that caused the problem.

I removed it and it worked fine.

Also as **Cyber aka THEGAMER** suggested, setting `margin: 0 !important;` to the tables did the trick too even without removing the `<br>`.